# Communications link failure Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.

Tags: java, android, mysql, database-connection

I tried to connect to `mysql database` but I failed and this error is shown

```
Communications link failure Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago
```

and this is my code ? anyone can help me please

```
package android_programmers_guide.testconnection;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TestConnection extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_connection);



           Connection conn = null;
           String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test";
           String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
           String userName = "root"; 
           String password = "root";


           try {
           Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);


           EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


           editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
           editText.setText("Connected to the database");

           conn.close();

           editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
           editText.setText("Disconnected from database");


           } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_test_connection, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: please check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358

Comment: are you sure that your MySQL database is running? or maybe the android_programmers_guide.testconnection class is trying to connect to a database on the android device

Comment: my database is running, sorry I didn't understand the second part. I'm begginer in Java

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because the URL you are passing is not working.

Check the following things:

1. Make sure that your localhost MySQL is running
2. Check the status of MySQL by typing `\s`.
3. Check the port number and make sure you are using the same one.

If all of the above is correct, maybe you don't have permissions.

Use `grant all on *.*` to  identified by "password",then run flush privileges, and then replace `127.0.0.1` with `localhost` and try to reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

The android application cannot communicate with the *mysql* in the same system. Because, when you run the android application it runs inside the *emulator*. The emulator is a  [virtual mobile device](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) like an android device. The *emulator* itself has an *ip* address.
So, according to the application the *ip* `127.0.0.1` is emulator's *ip*, therefore the android application will try to communicate with the *mysql* which is in the emulator. As we know, the emulator cannot have *mysql* in it, the communication will be failed. You can use *SQLite* for the data store.
If you want your android application to communicate with the *mysql*, you need install the *mysql* in another system and give that system's *ip*. Modify your code as follows :

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.102:3306/test";
```

Here, I mentioned `192.168.1.102` is second system's *ip*.
And do not forget to make a physical connection of these systems before trying.

For an additional knowledge :-
The direct communication of *mysql* with the android application is not a proper way.
Make a web application which communicates with the *mysql*.
Add a [web service](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webservices/what_are_web_services.htm) in it to store data into *mysql*. 
In the android application add a web layer which communicates with the web application through this web service.You can use *xml* or *[JSON](http://www.json.org/)* to transfer data from the android application to web application via web service.The web application should be storing data in to mysql which are received by the web service call of the android application.