# How to connect MySql in android Using JDBC Driver

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I am geting an Error Message while connecting to MySql Database using JDBC Driver.

Source code here,

And Error Message is

Communication Link failure.
Last Packet was send to the server was 0 ms ago

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.105:8081/onlineexam";
        private static final String user = "root";
        private static final String pass = "";

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            testDB();
        }

        public void testDB() {
            TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.exceptions);
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                /* System.out.println("Database connection success"); */

                String result = "Database connection success\n";
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from ft_users");
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

                while(rs.next()) {
                    result += rsmd.getColumnName(0) + ": " + rs.getInt(0) + "\n";
                    result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getString(1) + "\n";
                    result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
                }
                tv.setText(result);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tv.setText(e.toString());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Best way use api(webService)

Comment: Hi Puneet, There are people that already tried to answer this question. Check for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679990/communications-link-failure-last-packet-sent-to-the-server-was-1-ms-ago

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105529/how-to-connect-android-with-mysql-using-mysql-jdbc-driver?rq=1